# ASP.net - How to achieve CSS with constant values, arithmetic and string manipulation

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

When developing ASP.NET websites (using VB.NET web forms) - a lot of my time is spend writing CSS files and they always seem to get messy (code duplication) and very long.

All I want to achieve is to be able to manipulate the CSS using VB.NET code in the following ways:

- Use an integer variable to store my "golden" number 7 and use that for width, padding, margin etc where needed
- Use string variables to store my "golden" hex color codes e.g. "#44C5F2" and use them for color, background-color, border-color etc. where needed
- Use an integer variable to set the height of an element and have four child elements each with height: mynum / 4

I just want to use basic VB.net number and string manipulation in order to create a CSS file on the fly.

I understand that the end product - the CSS file shouldn't change much - it should at most change on a daily basis otherwise caching couldn't be used.

I also understand that I would lose Visual Studio CSS intellisense support but...

How do I achieve this?

Should I be using:

- Generic handlers (ASHX)
- ASP.NET Themes
- ASP.NET Skins
- Something else?

I just some pointers.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with a WebHandler (ASHX file) in the end:

CssOnTheFly.ashx

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="CssOnTheFly" CodeBehind="CssOnTheFly.ashx.cs" %>
```

CssOnTheFly.ashx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class CssOnTheFly : IHttpHandler
{

    private HttpResponse r;

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/css";

        r = context.Response;

        writeCss();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void writeCss()
    {
        wl("body {");
        wl("height: 100%;");
        wl("}");
    }

    private void wl(string s)
    {
        r.Write(s + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Because I could create bespoke classes to generate CSS on the fly - so I have more flexibility.

I think I need to use C# for this because VB.NET doesn't really have multi-line string literals.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for something like http://www.dotlesscss.org/

Comment: Is that using VB.NET code or the ASP.NET Razor syntax? Or is it a completely new syntax?

Comment: Call me lazy but I think I've got enough on my plate with ASP.NET, VB.NET, CSS, JavaScript, HTML, Regex, T-SQL, and LINQ-to-SQL already. I was hoping for a more .NET approach. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which extends CSS to allow

> dynamic behavior such as variables, mixins, operations and functions

[dot less](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) is a .NET version with integration to ASP.NET.

Comment: are there any other CSS metalanguages that work with ASP.NET?

Comment: None that I am aware of. dotless has great integration with ASP, I guess the other alternative would involve generating via ASP proper as you suggested in your question. LESS/dotless does have it's own syntax, but it is quick to pick up and I've found that rather than feeling like an extension to CSS it fills in some of the logical gaps, and it doesn't take long to learn.

Comment: Ok but is it a good idea to use this on commericial websites given that it is still in beta?

Comment: I've only used it for small non-important projects so I'm not in a position to say. Really you are looking at a tradeoff between the risk of running a beta product (which is reasonably popular, has had heavy coverage from top ASP bloggers) or writing your own. The former is likely to be more robust than a custom solution as it will have been used and tested by many, but you might find that you want to do more than dotless offers, which is where a custom solution *may* be more appropriate. I would at least spend some time evaluating dotless before making a final decision.